# How do I link an NDK static library (.a) with android CMake?

Tags: android, static, android-ndk, find

I wanna link the libgomp.a, but I had no success so far. :(
I've already tried find_library ( gomp-lib gomp ), but it doesn't find.
I don't know what else to do.

What is happening is that even though "#include " works, it doesn't find its function links when I try to use them. So I thought I had to link the static library some way. Android finds libxxx.so libraries just fine with find_library ( variable_name xxx). But not the (.a) ones.

Answer (score 0):

people! I just found out the problem.
In my gradle build I, on the cmake {} area, was using cFlags and cppFlags at the same time, and I just set the -fopenmp flag in the cFlags variable. The problem was solved when I also set the -fopenmp flag in the cppFlags. After this, I just erased the cFlags variable and started working only with the cppFlags.

At the end, I concluded that those static libraries (.a) are linked by to our NDK apps by default when, for example, I 'need' because of a flag, as I didn't need to do any linking on the cmake by myself.

Thank you all, I hoped this helps you all.

Comment: Would you please post your `build.gradle`, I have countered same problem ?